# Creating relationship based on IP and Type in Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

Dears,

I have a csv file with 10000 rows, I want to make father and child relationship as below:

Every group of relations have a Unique-Code and the relations will be defined based on each Unique Code . Also Only 3 type of Types Exist in all records A,B,C.

If the Type is A **and** the last digit of IP is **Even**, the Dep column must be fulfilled with **Father**  and Father-Name must be nothing.
If the Type is A **and** the Last digit of IP is **Odd**, the Dep column must be fulfilled with **Child**  and Father-Name must be the value with A Type and Even Ip address.

Now if the Type is *anything except A* the Dep column must be fulfilled with **Child** and the **Parent** of this child is the value with **Type of A and Odd IP address**.

I have the coded the first rule but don't know how to do it with second rule.

CSV file:

```
Unique-Code  Type          IP               Name       
   1          A       192.168.1.2           Part1
   1          A       192.168.1.1           Part2
   1          B       192.168.1.3           Part3
   1          C       192.168.1.4           Part4
   2          A       192.168.1.6           Part1
   2          A       192.168.1.7           Part2
   2          B       192.168.1.8           Part3
   2          C       192.168.1.9           Part4
```

Expected:

```
Unique-Code    Type        IP             Dep      Name    Father-Name
   1             A       192.168.1.2    Father   Part1         -
   1             A       192.168.1.1    Child    Part2        Part1
   1             B       192.168.1.3    Child    Part3        Part2
   1             C       192.168.1.4    Child    Part4        Part2
   2             A       192.168.1.6    Father   Part1         -
   2             A       192.168.1.7    Child    Part2        Part1
   2             B       192.168.1.8    Child    Part3        Part2
   2             C       192.168.1.9    Child    Part4        Part2
```

Python code:

```
df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Total.csv')
Father = df.loc[df['Type']=='A']
Father['Dep']= Father[IP].apply(lambda x:"Child" if int(x.split(".")[-1]) % 2 else  "Father")
```

Comment: im not quite understanding you instructions...

Comment: @adirabargil : I tried to clarify it more

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @JeffUK: I should make a dependency relationship with this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['LastDigit'] = df['IP'].str.strip().str[-1].astype(int)

df['Dep']= np.where((df['Type']=='A') & (df['LastDigit'] % 2 == 0), 'Father', 'Child')
df['Father-Name'] = np.where(df['Dep']=='Father','-',df['Name'])
```

which gives

```
  Unique-Code Type           IP   Name  LastDigit     Dep Father-Name
0            1    A  192.168.1.2  Part1          2  Father           -
1            1    A  192.168.1.1  Part2          1   Child       Part2
2            1    B  192.168.1.3  Part3          3   Child       Part3
3            1    C  192.168.1.4  Part4          4   Child       Part4
4            2    A  192.168.1.6  Part1          6  Father           -
5            2    A  192.168.1.7  Part2          7   Child       Part2
6            2    B  192.168.1.8  Part3          8   Child       Part3
7            2    C  192.168.1.9  Part4          9   Child       Part4
```

The replacement method you have for the Part 1,2 is unclear. explain it again and I'll fix it.

Maybe this

```
df['Father-Name_nw'] = np.where((df['Father-Name']=='Part2'), 'Part1', np.where(df['Father-Name']=='-','-','Part2'))
df = df.drop(['Father-Name'], axis=1)
```

which gives

```
  Unique-Code Type           IP   Name  LastDigit     Dep Father-Name_nw
0            1    A  192.168.1.2  Part1          2  Father              -
1            1    A  192.168.1.1  Part2          1   Child          Part1
2            1    B  192.168.1.3  Part3          3   Child          Part2
3            1    C  192.168.1.4  Part4          4   Child          Part2
4            2    A  192.168.1.6  Part1          6  Father              -
5            2    A  192.168.1.7  Part2          7   Child          Part1
6            2    B  192.168.1.8  Part3          8   Child          Part2
7            2    C  192.168.1.9  Part4          9   Child          Part2
```